# Why won't Evee open the selected material in compositing

Tags: materials, node-editor, interface, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

[image: Evee Bug]

I remember that in older versions of Blender the current material would be selected, if you chose an entity with a material.
As you can see in compositing editor, there should be some type of diffuse and image node.

Comment: Node editor needs to be shader type instead of texture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up some things here:

The node-based material definition process is not the same thing as "compositing". They share the feature of being node-based but they are not the same thing.

Since they are two separate things, Blender 2.8 split the editor into two: the "Compositing" editor and the "Shader Editor" (Eevee doesn't really matter here, this is an unrelated change).

[image]

The one that you find in the "Compositing" workspace is the compositing editor. The one you need is in the "Shading" workspace.

[image]

It is also in whatever workspace you want, if you select the editor type to be "Shader Editor".

[image]